# What is a measure of how easy it is to magnetize a material?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Is there a measure (i.e. is there a word for..) how easy it is to magnetize a particular material?

From some searching, I have found that 'coercivity' is a measure of how difficult it is to demagnetize a magnet.  I guess what I am looking for is the equivalent of that word for the magnetization side of the loop.

Eg. Material A is easy to magnetize, it has [high/low] XXXXX
Material B is difficult to magnetize, it has [high/low] XXXXX

Comment: Remanence is the nearest word I can think of. I have heard "magnetizability" used in this context in industry, but this can also mean simply the susceptibility of a material (*i.e.* the reversible magnetization arising from the presence of a magnetic field that disappears when the field is taken away).

Comment: BTW are you asking for the word meaning the ease of making a *permanent magnet* or the word meaning the reversible magnetization that arises from an applied magnetic field? If the latter, then Stephen's answer "susceptibility" is the word you need.

Comment: It's the former - the ease of making a permanent magnet.  More specifically, in a specific device it is important for a particular component to conduct magnetic flux well, but also important that the component itself does not become a permanent magnet due to its continued presence in a magnetic field...  So I think what I am looking for is a material with high permeability but low XXX???Mystery word

Comment: Yes - it looks like 'remanence' could be in

Answer (score 2):

I think the quantity you are looking for is [susceptibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_susceptibility), which is a measure of how the magnetization $M$ of a sample depends on the applied magnetic field $H$. For a paramagnetic (or diamagnetic) material, the susceptibility $\chi$ is defined by $M = \chi H$.

But for a ferromagnet, things are more complicated, because the magnetization can be nonzero in zero applied field. In that case, one can define the differential susceptibility as the derivative $\frac{\partial M}{\partial H}$. (In fact, $M$ and $H$ are vectors, so $\chi$ is a matrix.) You can determine this by looking at the slope of the lines on a hysteresis plot (such as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercivity)). Because it depends on the history of the sample, you can't just quote a number, as you can for a paramagnet like water.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies susceptibility somewhat for me, but I don't think it's the word I'm looking for because it describes the temporary magnetization according to Rod Vance, above.